# Server Fileshare Office Documents Read Only until Closing and Reopening

Tags: windows-server-2003, microsoft-office, read-only

Have a customer that has a strange issue with Microsoft Office Documents on their file server. It does not happen every time they open an office file but it is pretty consistent. They get a read only message when they open the document the first time but if they close out of it and reopen it then it opens fine and can work in it just fine.

I know that there is no other users accessing the same file. We are seeing this with the Microsoft Office 2010 users along with the Microsoft Office 2013 users. In accounting they have seen this issue with opening TIF documents but they are allowed to save over the original file just fine.

The user end users are running Windows 7 Professional and the server is Microsoft Server 2003 Standard R2.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,

Garrett

Comment: Curious why you tagged this with the O365 tag?  Also, does the file server have a real-time virus scanner on it?  If so, have you tried disabling it for a while just to see if that helps?

Comment: Sheer accident on the Office 365 tag. Yes to the disabling it. Did not do anything. We use ESET File Security on these servers.

Answer (score 0):

The last time I saw this behaviour it was client side antivirus locking the file while scanning it.  Whether or not it ended up read only seemed to depend on network bandwidth or latency as remote sites had more issues.

Anything else that accesses any file that is opened could cause this behaviour.  Antivirus being the most common but some backup software and malware could do it too.

It seemed to be a race condition.  Most of the time the antivirus would finish its scan before word finished loading.  But on slow links word often finished while the file was still being scanned.

Comment: Thanks so much for the information. I will try this tomorrow and report back to let you know. Thanks again!